# What's the name of this component of the turbofan engines?

Tags: turbofan

Almost many of turbofan engines that I've seen so far nowadays had a part like a small wing. what do you call them? here is some pictures of the thing I'm asking question about:

[image: figure1]

[image: figure2]

[image: figure3]

[image: figure4]

Comment: The actual nomenclature would be a "strake" or "chine".